# Php to redirect to a url by adding wmsauth from another site

Tags: php

I had an issue in my php code in which I first read the WMS auth sign from another site and then I place that WMS auth sign in a URL and then redirect to that URL with WMS auth sign 
The code which I am using is below

```
<?php 
$token = readfile("http://51.15.209.90:8800/fio/3b.rbt/");
header("Location: http://zer0live.hjkm.info:13292/neptune/colorstv/playlist.m3u8" . $token); 
exit; 
?>
```

Can anyone please correct this code 
Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you check what `readfile()` does [in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) it sends what it reads DIRECTLY to the output buffer, so you dont get to play with what it reads before that.

So try using `file_get_contents()` instead.

```
$token = file_get_contents("http://51.15.209.90:8800/fio/3b.rbt/");
header("Location: http://zer0live.hjkm.info:13292/neptune/colorstv/playlist.m3u8$token"); 
exit;
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this:

```
<?php 
$token: readfile("http://51.15.209.90:8800/fio/3b.rbt/");



header('Location: http://zer0live.hjkm.info:13292/neptune/colorstv/playlist.m3u8'.$token); 




exit; 
?>
```